# how to calculate the number of days between two different dates

Tags: c

I am using a formula to calculate the number of days between two different days in calendar, and I am not getting the same answers as the examples I am looking at. I am trying to follow the following formula:

N = 1461 x f(year, month) / 4 + g(month) / 5 + day

Where 
f (year, month) = year -1 if month <= 2. Otherwise the same value is returned. 
g(month) = month + 13 if month <= 2. Otherwise it is month+1.

Here is how I implemented the above formula:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEBUG

  struct date
    {
      int month ;
      int day ;
      int year ;
    };
  int een (struct date _date)
    {
      int n;
      #ifdef DEBUG
      printf("inside of een function - here is what is in date %i/%i/%i \n", _date.month, _date.day, _date.year);
      #endif
      n = 1461 * f(_date.year, _date.month) / 4 + 153 * g(_date.month) / 5 + _date.day;
      #ifdef DEBUG
      printf("Here is the value of n %i \n", n);
      #endif
      return n;
    }
  int f(int year, int month)
    {
      if (month <= 2)
      year = (year - 1);
      return year;
    }
   int g(int month)
    {
      if (month <= 2)
        month = month + 13;
      else
      month = month +1;
      return month;
    }
int main (void)
{
  struct date first_Day, second_Day;
    int days;
  int een (struct date _date);
  printf ("Enter the first date (mm dd yyyy) :");
  scanf ("%i%i%i", &first_Day.month, &first_Day.day, &first_Day.year);
  #ifdef DEBUG
  printf("Here is what you entered as the first date %i/%i/%i \n", first_Day.month, first_Day.day, first_Day.year);
  #endif
  printf ("Enter Today's date (mm dd yyyy) :");
  scanf ("%i%i%i", &second_Day.month, &second_Day.day, &second_Day.year);
  days = een (second_Day) - een (first_Day);
  printf("Here are the number of days between the dates you put in  %i \n ", days);
}
```

One example I am looking at calculates N for August 8, 2004 as follows:

N = 1461 x f(2004, 8) / 4 + 153 x g(8) / 5 + 3

I know the above code has some issues. I also don't know how he/she gets 3 for August 8th. I am hoping someone may have used this formula before, and they can explain if the example above is wrong or that it needs additional explanation. I have looked at other posts about this type of code, and they don't discuss my question. I have also looked into other sites, but have not been able to find the answer. I know that timeanddate.com has a calculator, and according to it, my code above does not work.

I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone else has used this formula before, and get some feedback. I'll then just use 12 in the g() function.

Here are two sample calculations according to the author. For August, 8 2004 he gets:

```
N= 1461 x f(2004, 8) / 4 + 153 x g(8) / 5 + 3 
= (1461 x 2004) / 4 + (153 x 9) / 5 + 3 
= 2,927,844 / 4 + (153 x 9) / 5 + 3
= 731,961 + 275 + 3
= 732,239
```

For Feb 22, 2005 he gets:

```
1461 x f(2005, 2) / 4 + 153 x g(2) / 5 + 21
(1461 x 2004) / 4 + 2295 / 5 + 21 
731961 + 459 + 21 
732,441
```

Number of days in between: 731,441 - 732,239 = 202

Frankly I am not sure how he comes up with 3 and 21 for the "day" values in the above samples.

I also checked my answer [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=08&d1=08&y1=2004&m2=2&d2=22&y2=2005&ti=on) and it says 199 days. I think I would be ok if I could just figure out how the day variable for the above dates was calculated. I guess there is some variance, which depends on how the extra four hours in each year is treated.

Comment: Suggest `month = month + 13;` --> `month = month + 12;`

Comment: I agree with @chux, the `g()` function in the code does not reflect the formula you described in the question. Either you put a `else` after `month = month + 13;` or you sum 12 instead of 13, since month will always be incremented by `month = month +1;`

Comment: Or convert both of your dates to `time_t` and find the difference (e.g. `difftime`), then simply `days = ( seconds / (60*60*24)` (you can continue to get the additional hours, min secs from the fractional part if you like)

Comment: I added the else. I get 198 instead of 202 days as an answer to the difference between August, 8 2004 and February 22, 2005. I'll update my code above. It is still wrong though.

Comment: A google search shows a sample [implementation](https://paste.teknik.io/Raw/2299) of this.  No idea how the comments come up with 3 for the day for both the 8th and 22nd of the month. Looks like a comment bug. Maybe you can't believe every code sample you find on the internet?

Comment: @evaitl- Yea I saw that page, and I am glad you mentioned it. I wish I had put a link to it instead of typing the calculation; but some may not have looked there. I am following the same formula, but with my own code. Does anyone know how they get the day value? That is what I can not figure out.

Comment: Well tested and efficient date algorithms which are valid over a ridiculously large range:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html  They happen to count 1970-01-01 as day 0, but the algorithms are valid +/- millions of years (more if you compute with 64 bits).  Fully documented.  Complete derivation.

Comment: some years ago, I worked on an embedded system, where it had a 32 bit clock counter, and I had to make it produce an accurate date from 'now' to the year 3000 (which is beyond the ability of a 32 bit clock register to directly count.  I spent several months trying to enhance the existing code, before I finally figgured out how to do it.  It was not at all simple

Answer (score 0):

In windows you could do something like this:

```
__int64  since_ft, until_ft;
SYSTEMTIME since, until;

SystemTimeToFileTime(&since, (LPFILETIME)&since_ft);
SystemTimeToFileTime(&until, (LPFILETIME)&until_ft);
int days = (int)((until_ft - since_ft) / (__int64)864000000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I added the else. I get 198 instead of 202 days as an answer to the difference between August, 8 2004 and February 22, 2005. I'll update my code above. It is still wrong though.

Actually, your code may be correct.

As a cross check, below is an approach that uses `mktime` [*Side note:* which handles leap years] to get absolute times, takes the difference, and divides to get the number of days. This is similar to what David was suggesting.

Its output is `198`, just like yours. I think it's pretty accurate, but even with an off-by-one error, that would still make the answer `197-199`. IMO, `202` is just too high.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t
timeof(int mon,int day,int yr)
{
    struct tm tm;
    time_t tod;

    memset(&tm,0,sizeof(tm));

    tm.tm_year = yr - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = mon - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = day;

    // minimize funny business with DST crossover or [gag] leap seconds
    tm.tm_hour = 1;

    tod = mktime(&tm);

    return tod;
}

int
main(void)
{
    time_t t1;
    time_t t2;
    time_t td;

    t1 = timeof(8,8,2004);
    t2 = timeof(2,22,2005);

    td = t2 - t1;
    td /= (24 * 60 * 60);

    printf("%ld\n",td);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can check your date arithmetic quickly with the GNU date utility:

```
$ date -d 'August 8 2004 + 198 days'
Tue Feb 22 00:00:00 EST 2005
```

So I'd stick with 198 as an answer.

Comment: This makes me feel better about what I have. I posted the sample calculation the author provided to check our answer against. There may be a typo some where in original calculation.